# Where to get multiple Public IP addresses from?

Tags: linux-networking, datacenter

I have a broadband connection that has one single Public IP address,

Now I want to set up a home datacenter with OpenStack,

My problem is that whenever I launch a new VPS in my master server, each VPS needs a Public IP address in order to be accessible from the outer world.

I understand that I can add IP address and pools,
However, How can I get those extra IP address?

From my ISP?
And how costly can it be?
How many ip addresses can I have? is there a limit?

Sorry, noob here.

Comment: If you have a consumer grade broadband connection you aren't getting more addresses, and you are probably violating your terms of service.  As your questions, it is all completely up to the ISP.  There is not 'standard' here.  Call them.

Comment: In various ways you can overwork this requirement. For example you may redirect transfer to any of VPS via assigning specific port to stream to particular VPS machine ( PAT). So basically it depends, and in many circumstances, for small infrastructure, you don't need a lot of public ip4 addresses. Saying that, I would comment, that as you are asking, pat infrastructure is probably far enough for your size and knowledge level.

Comment: @hack4mer I can provide you the service for your project, no need a big investment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not necessarily need more IPv4 addresses, you might be able to use IPv6 or NAT.

However, if you determine that you do need/want more IPv4 addresses, they must be from your ISP, either your current or another that provides multiple IPs, as they must be routed to you.

In general, there is a shortage of IPv4 addresses, so you usually have to specify a reason why you would need them, in addition to recurring payments.

Comment: Thank you, so when AWS and Azure give us instant IP addresses when we launch a virtual server on their cloud platform, they are getting it from the ISP? (hypothetically, I know these giants are ISP themselves)

Comment: They already have a pool of IP addresses, from their ISPs or from IANA, and allocate one of the free addresses. If they needed to order one when you start up your instance, you would have to wait days or weeks for your instance to start.

Comment: Very helpful information. I googled a few things based upon this info and came across some websites that sell ipv4 addresses, like this one: https://www.ipv4auctions.com/

Can I buy these and use them to reach my home-hosted vps?

Comment: What quantity are you talking about? That website sells 256 or more addresses. An address pool without routing is useless for you. You would need to convince your ISP to route the addresses to you, and it is easier for them to route a part of their own address space than some random addresses. So it would be better to ask your ISP or find another ISP that already offers multiple addresses.